# Different screen size layout on Android

Tags: android

I created layouts for each screen. as `sw300dp`, `sw360dp`, `sw420dp`, `sw600dp` and `sw720dp`. But there are different screen sizes that support `sw-360dp`. For example, 1080x1920 and 1080x2280 images change in my changes to `sw360`. The image is distorted because the two screen sizes are different.

How can I solve this problem?

[image: emulator screen size]
[image: layout source]

Comment: You can't 'catch' all screen variations this way. There will always be more different types now or in the future. You should instead learn how to make layouts that will scale acceptably to different window sizes. Especially when you consider things like split-screen and free-form windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want enforce certain size (which in discouraged, because android devices varies in screen ratios, sizes and densities in large extent, and there always be some device, where image will be distorted) you can add constraint for minimum height, like `drawable-sw360dp-h1024dp`.
Or simply use proper scaleType for imageview.

Comment: Thank you. How can I make this limitation? I couldn't understand your logic?

Comment: you can create folder, like `layout-w720dp-h360dp` for layouts in res folder, and find width and height value constraint (like for 720 dp width it will be `layout-w720dp` for 360 dp height it will be `layout-w720dp-h360dp`)that will match your needs